# I keep getting a blank screen in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following a tutorial and my localhost is completely blank after importing {Link} from react-router-dom. Followed word for word but my local host is blank as soon as I added link in navbar.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
    return(
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
            
                <Link to="/" class="navbar-brand">SkyCloud</Link>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-togglser-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/" class="nav-link active">Home</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/about" class="nav-link active">About</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/contact" class="nav-link active">Contact</Link>
                    </li>

                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
      </nav>  

    );




}

export default Navbar;
```

And this is my App.js file...

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/inc/Navbar';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'; 

function App() {
  return (
    
    <Router>
    <div>
     <Navbar/>
    <Home/>
   <About/>
   <Contact/>

  
    </div>
    </Router>
    
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: is there an error in the browser console?

Comment: Which version react router dom you use v5 or v6 ?

Comment: @KhandkerAshikMahmud I'm using react router dom v6 I think. All I did was npm install react-router-dom. So I think it's version 6.

Comment: @about14sheep there wasn't any error in the browser console. Everything seems to be running fine. But localhost is blank after I added Link. In Navbar.js.

Comment: Can you please send error which show in console.

Comment: @sedhalsoni there wasn't any error in console. It says that it has been compiled successfully. But LocalHost is blank. Before I added Link. It was fine but when I added it in navbar.js and imported it. LocalHost became blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your components inside Route HOC, if you are using react router v5

```
 <Route path="/">
    <Home/>
 </Route>
 <Route path="/about">
   <About/>
 </Route>
 <Route path="/Contact">
   <Contact/>
 </Route>
```

if its react router v6, answer is

```
  <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contact/>} />
  <Route path=/about" element={<About/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import Routes and Route too from "react-router-dom";

then your code will become

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/inc/Navbar';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import {Routes,Route ,BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'; 

function App() {
  return (
    
<Router>
 <div>
 <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}>
        <Route path="/about" element={ <About/>}>
        <Route path="/contact" element={ <Contact/>} />
    </Routes>
 </div>
</Router>
    
   
  );
```

Comment: Hi I tried that but I ended up getting the corresponding two errors.                                                                                                                
 "Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Route>. (19:7)", Line 19    Please  Help

Comment: sorry i had an error in the code and i ve rectified it , you can try it now !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which version you use . please check package.json and search react-router-dom . Then you will see the version.
(React router dom v6)
If you use link ,You need to use router and routes. I think no error is shown your project. This is the documentation

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation#create-react-app

This is demo code of routes , route

```
       import * as React from "react";
       import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

       function App() {
        return (
         <div className="App">
            <h1>Welcome to React Router!</h1>
             <Routes>
               <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
               <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
      );
     }
```

If you Use V5

```
 import {
   BrowserRouter,
   Switch,
   Route,
   Link,
   useRouteMatch
  } from "react-router-dom";

 function App() {
   return (
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
         <Home />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/users">
         <Users />
       </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
 ); 
}
```

react router dom v5 documentation
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, just edit this navbar as per your need

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar bg='light' expand='lg'>
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to='/'>
            <Navbar.Brand>Brand</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
          <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
            <Nav className='ml-auto'>
              <LinkContainer to='/cart'>
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i> Cart
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to='/login'>
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className='fas fa-user'></i> SignIn
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all your Components are spelled corrected, eg:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

BAD:

```
<link to="#" className="backtotop">
Back to top
</link>
```

Good:

```
<Link to="#" className="backtotop">
Back to top
</Link>
```